# Spring security logout not working because of CORS

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, axios

**Technologies:** Spring Security, Spring Boot on backend and ReactJs and axios on front-end.

**What I want to have:** When hitting a `logout` button on my front-end I want to log out the user. In order to do so I make a call to backend using `delete`. Then I want my backend to log out.

**My issue:** When I call Spring Security `logout` endpoint from my front-end I receive the following message: 
`Failed to load http://localhost:8080/logout: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8888' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.` I do understand why I have this error - backend is on localhost:8080 and front-end on localhost:8888. But what I **don't** understand is why my configuration doesn't work for logout, while it works perfectly fine for all other situations (e.g. calling spring security `login` endpoint or some of my custom endpoints).

**How I make the call from the front-end**

```
const endpoint = 'logout';
return axios.delete(
    'http://localhost:8080/' + `${endpoint}`,
    {withCredentials: true}
)
    .then(response => {
        let resp = {
            httpCode: response.status,
            data: response.data
        };
        return {response: resp};
    })
    .catch(error => {
        let err = {
            httpStatusCode: error.response.status,
            message: `Error calling endpoint ${endpoint}`
        };
        return {error: err};
    });
```

**Enabling CORS from front-end**

```
@Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8888");
            }
        };
    }
```

**SecurityConfig.java** - here you might notice some parts are commented - they are other solutions I tried but they didn't work.

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = UsersRepository.class)
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationSuccessHandler restAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationFailureHandler restAuthenticationFailureHandler;
    @Bean
    public CustomLogoutHandler customLogoutHandler(){
        return new CustomLogoutHandler();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(getPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("**/anna/**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .addLogoutHandler(customLogoutHandler())
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"));
        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint);
        http.formLogin().successHandler(restAuthenticationSuccessHandler);
        http.formLogin().failureHandler(restAuthenticationFailureHandler);

//        http
//                .logout()
//                .logoutUrl("/logout")
//                .addLogoutHandler(new CustomLogoutHandler())
//                .invalidateHttpSession(true);

//        http
//                .cors()
//                .and()
//                .csrf().disable()
//                .logout()
//                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"));
    }

    private PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return new PasswordEncoder() {
            @Override
            public String encode(CharSequence charSequence) {
                return charSequence.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean matches(CharSequence charSequence, String s) {
                return true;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**CustomLogoutHandler.java** I read somewhere about the solution with setting the header here. I guess it's bad practice and would prefer not to do it, but basically I'd be happy to see the log working. Currently it's not logging anything so my guess it that it's not called on logout.

```
//@Slf4j
public class CustomLogoutHandler implements LogoutHandler{
    @Override
    public void logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication){
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        System.out.println("TodosLogoutHandler logging you out of the back-end app.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `DELETE /logout`? That's quiet unexpected and far away from best practice in my opinion. There's no resource to delete at /logout. I suggest `POST /logout` or `DELETE /session`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'll go with `POST/logout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the source code of [`CorsRegistration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/cors/CorsConfiguration.java#L331),

```
public CorsConfiguration applyPermitDefaultValues() {
        [...]
        if (this.allowedMethods == null) {
            this.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList(
                    HttpMethod.GET.name(), HttpMethod.HEAD.name(), HttpMethod.POST.name()));
        }
        [...]
        return this;
    }
```

As you can see, the `Delete` method is **NOT ALLOWED** by default, So you need add the `delete` method.

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
  return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                            .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8888")
                            .addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.DELETE);
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: That was the issue. Thank you a lot!